# Send emails and avoid spam folder (C# WPF / DKIM & SPF)

Tags: c#, email

I'm making a WPF local application in C# and I wanted to send emails for registering confirmation, the problem is that the mails always arrives in the spam folder. I think that the missing part is the DKIM and SPF configuration, I'm using MandrillApp who tell me to add a DKIM and a SPF entry in my DNS zone. Where can I configure the DKIM and the SPF entry in my local project ? What is the best way to send emails and avoid the spam folder?

The application is local and I use the MandrillApp services who helps to send transactional emails.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that your email's body doesn't contains too many links or content may have some text which force to put them in span.
Because email provider tracks the email content and if the email content not follows all the protocol then these emails are sent to span folder.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have your system sending emails successfully, but they are all being sent to the recipient's spam mailbox?

If that is the case, there can be many things which cause your email to end up in the spam folder.

Ultimately, emails are awarded spam points when they are missing certain criteria, or originate from weird places/servers. Once you are over a certain number of points, your email get's spam classification.

I have never used MandrillApp, (By Mailchimp) but I am guessing there is some setup required between you and them.
Are your emails coming from your domain name, or Mandrills?

One of the biggest issues I have seen is actually a DNS issue, where the outgoing mail server is not setup properly. I am guessing you want your emails to look like they come from your domain??

Also, suspicious looking email subjects can cause you to be awarded relatively large numbers of spam points.

Other things which get you spam points:
Missing HTML and plainext versions of your email
Mail body content which looks generated
Originating servers can be blacklisted/graylisted
Lots of contacts in the TO/CC fields
Etc...

Here is Mailchimps SPAM information as a pointer:
http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/how-to-avoid-spam-filters/html/

For further reading, search for Avoiding Spam Points, or Preventing mail to be classed as spam or something similar.

I hope that helps.

Regards.